# How to make UIWebView/WKWebView behave like the Safari browser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I would like to create a `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` which behaves like Safari browser in phone. I tried launching my URLS in native Safari browser, but could not find a way to pass the cookies. I asked that too but did not get an answer.

Basicly, I need the functionality to interact with files in the web page which requires authorization first. For example, you can download the images to gallery in Safari, or download PDFs to device.

How to enable user to interact files in webview?

Comment: check SFSafariViewController  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-sfsafariviewcontroller--cms-24260

Comment: Second that. `SFSafariViewController` is supposed to give you the full functionality of Safari, (cookies, etc.) within your own app.

Comment: If I save a file in SFSafariViewController, does it save to apps own storage, or common storage?

Comment: It seems it saves to common storage which is nice. Another question, how to seet cookies to SFSafariViewController?